# Setting ContentView height in a ScrollView to change dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have been struggling with this for days now and I hope there is someone who can help.

My structure looks something like this:

```
UIView
|---UIScrollView
    |---UIContentView
        |---UIHeaderView
        |---UITableView
        |---UITCollectionView
```

I set my **heights** and my **constraints** to 0 (I also tired to set it to 3600 for testing purposes) in *Interface Builder* and then I run a *for loop* to get the heights of all the views inside UIContentView **after all the subviews are loaded**:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var contentRect = CGRect.zero

    for view in contentView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }
    contentHeightConstraint.constant = contentRect.height
}
```

I also call a method to reload the table and update subviews at *cellForRowAt indexPath* and when I *retrieveData* And *retrieveImages* FromFirebase:

```
func configureTableView() {

    self.postTableHeightConstraint.constant = postTableView.contentSize.height

    postTableView.reloadData()
    postTableView.layoutSubviews()
    postTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

My *Autolayout* is set up correctly because everything scrolls and looks right but for some reason it does not create enough scroll area, it is as if it only loads about 75% of the required scrollable space in my contentView.

It is as if it overrides the values it calculates in **viewDidLayoutSubViews** with the ones I set as placeholders in *Interface Builder*

I have tried all of these:

1. Set the *heightConstraint* of the **contentView** = contentRect.height
2. Set the *heightConstraint* of the **scrollView** = contentRect.height
3. Set the *heightConstraint* of the **tableView** = contentRect.height
4. Tried a c**ombination** of the above

None of who seem to work, what am I missing?

Comment: You should be calling `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` first thing in your override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Autolayout will do this for you if you just constrain the 4 edges of the contentView to the scrollView edges, and then make sure you have a complete chain of constraints from the top of the content view to the bottom (so that AutoLayout can compute the height of the content).

Comment: I added super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() - still doesn't calculate accurately, the reason I can't rely on Autolayout to do determine the height is because my UITableview row heights also change? Will Autlayout know to calculate those as well when it determines the scrollView's contentView height?

Comment: You're right.  Autolayout wouldn't know to change the tableHeight to show all of the content, so you'd still need to do that.  But if you connect your items with constraints, you could avoid having to add up the frames to compute the contentView's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I moved my **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** code into a new custom method, and called it every time I finished my **configureTableView()** method

```
func calcTotalHeight() {
    for view in contentView.subviews {
        self.contentRect = self.contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }
    contentHeightConstraint.constant = self.contentRect.height
    contentView.needsUpdateConstraints()
}

func configureTableView() {

    //1. Set Table Row dimensions
    postTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    postTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 375

    //2. Update Table View and reload contentview
    postTableView.reloadData()
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    //3. Update Table View Height
    self.postTableHeightConstraint.constant = postTableView.contentSize.height

    //4. Reload ContentView and Recalculate New Height of Content View
    contentView.layoutSubviews()
    calcTotalHeight()
}
```

Not the most eloquent solution but it works, and does not produce too much overhead on loading.

Also it is **important** to point out that the order in which reloadData, layoutIfNeeded and layoutSubviews in relation to the other code plays a critical part in getting this to work.